# Insert Image in a <td> with different resolution

Tags: html, image, resolution, html-table

I have a table with 3 rows and one of that is this one:

```
  <tr>
  <td>Logo Programma</td>
  <td>Giorno</td>
  <td>Giorno</td>
  <td>Put the image here</td>
  </tr>
```

Now I want to add an image and I have used the tag  like this

```
<td><img src="image.jpg" alt=""></td>
```

The resolution is 788x592 but I don't want to use 788x592 pixels, it will be huge!
So I want to keep the proportions but with less resolution.

Comment: Could you try JSFiddle?

Comment: you can change your image size `<img  width="100" height="100"/>` !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To keep the proportions of the image while setting a new size do something like this:

```
<td><img src="image.jpg" alt="" style="width:200px; height:auto;"></td>
```

This will set the width to `200px` and the height will automatically adjust to keep proportions.. you can also calculate the height that should be and add it as a fixed number.

Answer (score -5):

Use `height` and `width` of `img` tag, like that:

```
<img src="image.jpg" width="100" height="200" alt="">
```

***Edit*** If only one dimension is known, you can omit second measurement and the image will `scale` accordingly.

Comment: Yes it will, when you substitute real numbers.